# How do you install PyDDE to Python 3.4 and not Python 2.4

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am currently trying to install the PyDDE package.

Going to the command line and running pip install PyDDE initially didn't work, so I downloaded the zip package from https://github.com/hensing/PyDDE

and then I navigated to the unzipped folder and used the python setup.py command as specified in the installation instruction.

This installed the PyDDE module in python 2.7, and typing import PyDDE yields the module in 2.7. However, it does not install in 3.4.

I found this similar problem on stackoverflow ( 
[Python 3.4 and 2.7: Cannot install numpy package for python 3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24892810/python-3-4-and-2-7-cannot-install-numpy-package-for-python-3-4)

[Installing numpy for Python 2.7 while also having Python 3.4 installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25900818/installing-numpy-for-python-2-7-while-also-having-python-3-4-installed)

which provided solutions like using sudo pip and going to the python 3.4 folder and using easy_install PyDDE

Since it is already installed for python 2.7 when I use:
easy_install PyDDE or
pip install PyDDE
it happily tells me that pydde 0.2.2 is already installed/the active version, however, loading up Python 3.4 and importing PyDDE still doesn't work.
I have also tried python34 install PyDDE but python34 isn't a recognised command.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `pip3`:

```
pip3 install PyDDE
```

`pip` installs python2 packages and `pip3` does your python3 packages.

You need python3 in your pythonpath go to:

```
My Computer/Properties/Advanced System Settings/Environment Variables
```

And add `C:\Python34\;C:\Python34\Scripts\` to your pythonpath.

Then download [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) and run `python34 get-pip.py`

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me - I ge back 'pip3' is not recognised as an internal or external operable program or batch file

Comment: so you are on windows?  Have you added python3 to your environment variables? You need  `"C:\Python34\;C:\Python34\Scripts\"`  in there

Comment: `My Computer /Properties /Advanced System Settings /Environment Variables `

Comment: Thanks for the reply but still not getting any joy getting it to work: I've navigated to the environment variables and where it used to say: C:\Users\Simon\Anaconda;C:\Users\Simon\Anaconda\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\SSH Communications Security\SSH Secure Shell  it now says: C:\Users\Simon\Anaconda;C:\Users\Simon\Anaconda\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\SSH Communications Security\SSH Secure Shell;C:\Python34\;C:\Python34\Scripts       I've tried pip3 install PyDDE and pip3 is not a recognised... and yes, python34 is c:\Python34

Comment: have you installed pip as suggested in the edit to my answer? You may also need to logout and in after adding the path

Comment: for the last part - run python34 get-pip.py, I presume I navigate to the folder where I downloaded get-pip.py and type in python get-pip.py? If so python34 is still not recognised

Comment: If you added the path to your pythonpath correctly you can run python3 from anywhere, just make sure you log out and in.

Comment: you have actually installed  python3.4 and see the python34 folder  in C: yes?

Comment: Yes, python 3.4 is installed and the folder is in C: as c:/Python34

Comment: so when you go in the folder you can run python34?

Comment: Yes, on the command line, if I go to c:\Python34 and then type Python, Python 3.4.3 runs. However it does not seem to run anywhere else by typing python34.

Comment: then your path is not correct,  did you logout and in?

Comment: I did - its not solved but in the meantime I have got it working on a college Mac, but thanks for your help.