# How to install PyDDE using pip

Tags: pip, delay

I can use only pip to install python packages on external computer.
How can I install PyDDE package using pip?

http://users.ox.ac.uk/~clme1073/python/PyDDE/

Comment: Possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29198978/how-do-you-install-pydde-to-python-3-4-and-not-python-2-4

Comment: It is not working with pip3:   Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyDDE (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for PyDDE

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you install PyDDE to Python 3.4 and not Python 2.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29198978/how-do-you-install-pydde-to-python-3-4-and-not-python-2-4)